# AttributeError: module 'librosa' has no attribute 'output'

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, ffmpeg, librosa

I am using librosa 0.6 in anaconda and i have also installed ffmpeg but i am still getting this error

the code is

```
a = np.exp(spectrum) - 1
    p = 2 * np.pi * np.random.random_sample(spectrum.shape) - np.pi
    for i in range(50):
        S = a * np.exp(1j * p)
        x = librosa.istft(S)
        p = np.angle(librosa.stft(x, N_FFT))
    librosa.output.write_wav(outfile, x, sr)
```

Answer (score 33):

you can use this instead

```
import soundfile as sf
sf.write('stereo_file1.wav', reduced_noise, 48000, 'PCM_24')
```

check more here https://pysoundfile.readthedocs.io/en/0.8.1/#soundfile.write

Answer (score 23):

The function `librosa.output` was removed in librosa version `0.8.0`. This is documented in [their changelog](https://librosa.org/doc/latest/changelog.html?highlight=output#v0-8-0).

So, the most likely reason for your issue, is that you are using this new version of librosa (and not version 0.6.x).  You can verify by doing `print(librosa.__version__)`.

With modern librosa,  you should instead use [soundfile.write](https://pysoundfile.readthedocs.io/en/0.8.1/#soundfile.write) to write audio output.